# What is the most efficient way to SELECT data from a second SQL Server instance?

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, performance

We have an app that uses ASP.NET MVC3 and SQL Server 2008 that works fine. We need to retrieve data from a SQL 2000 database for use in the MVC app. We have linked the SQL 2000 to SQL 2008 and created views on the SQL 2008 machine to read data, however performance is horrible. We even tested putting the two databases on the same machine and using views to read form one to the other, but the results were similar. It seems using views to read from a second datasource is simply not an option.

What is the best way to read data from the second machine? We only require read access, but can't have a dedicated connection from the MVC app, only a secure SQL to SQL connection (it's an accounting system)

UPDATE: SSMS selects the views as expected (no joins, under 1000 rows), however other clients connections take 10-15 seconds to display the view. Provider possibly?

Comment: We'd need to know why the performance is so bad. Are the databases normalised? How much does performance drop accessing via a different machine? If you use SSMS and normal T-SQL queries is the performance still bad? How much data are you accessing? How many tables are you joining on? Seriously, there are a huge number of potential reasons for poor performance, especially if you're trying to do it client-side.

Comment: If you issue a query to the linked server directly from SSMS is the performance equally bad? Just so we have some context here, how much data are we talking about and what qualifies as horrible performance?

Comment: Data is not huge (under 1000 rows per table) and there are no joins. Just SELECT * FROM table for the views. Oddly, in SSMS querying the view returns as expected (0.0 sec, 784 records). However, running it from the MVC app or from Navicat on OSX, performance is reduced to around 15 seconds. Is there a connection parameter that is required?

Comment: See my comment below....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer. ANSI_NULLS needed to be set to TRUE on the database. This issue is difficult to Google for since SQL Server "views" get hijacked by ASP.NET MVC "views". All select statements from native tables worked flawlessly, however an MVC app using DBMSSOCN that selects from a SQL view needs ANSI_NULLS to be set to TRUE on the database. Hopefully that saves someone else a lot of time.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Thank you for following up with your solution.